# Merge several tables

Tags: r, radix

Is want to merge several tables, in which there is one with unbalanced rows in comparison to the rest (tabacos0)
I would like the title of the table to appear if it is possible (Hipertensión, Diabetes..), make the NA previous to the table disappear. This comes from frequency tables done individually, if you know anyway to do it all at once, be my guest!

```
# I just put the syntax of one of the tables
hta_tb_grup <-with(dat, table(hta0, grup_int,  dnn = ("Hipertension")))
hta_tb_grupo_p <- with(dat, prop.table(hta_tb_grup, margin = 1))

> hta_tb_grupo_p
            NA
Hipertension         1         2         3
           0 0.3543614 0.3348910 0.3107477
           1 0.3387960 0.3284115 0.3327925
           9        

> diab_tb_grupo_p
        NA
Diabetes         1         2         3
       0 0.3287025 0.3420708 0.3292267
       1 0.3549009 0.3163546 0.3287445
       9  

> colest_tb_grupo_p
          NA
Dislipemia         1         2         3
         0 0.3499758 0.3174988 0.3325254
         1 0.3382244 0.3341382 0.3276374
         9 

> tabacos_tb_grupo_p
       NA
Fumador         1         2         3
      1 0.3371538 0.3390640 0.3237822
      2 0.3058252 0.3592233 0.3349515
      3 0.3297872 0.4007092 0.2695035
      4 0.3424759 0.3313566 0.3261675
      5 0.3445102 0.3210607 0.3344291
      9        

> rbind(hta_tb_grupo_p, diab_tb_grupo_p, colest_tb_grupo_p, tabacos_tb_grupo_p)                      

 1         2         3
0 0.3543614 0.3348910 0.3107477
1 0.3387960 0.3284115 0.3327925
9       NaN       NaN       NaN
0 0.3287025 0.3420708 0.3292267
1 0.3549009 0.3163546 0.3287445
9       NaN       NaN       NaN
0 0.3499758 0.3174988 0.3325254
1 0.3382244 0.3341382 0.3276374
9       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 0.3371538 0.3390640 0.3237822
2 0.3058252 0.3592233 0.3349515
3 0.3297872 0.4007092 0.2695035
4 0.3424759 0.3313566 0.3261675
5 0.3445102 0.3210607 0.3344291
9       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

```
Update: expected output. I am using database from spss with haven, but a I am not using labels instead of factors right now. 

        1         2         3
hta
0    0.3543614 0.3348910 0.3107477
1   0.3387960 0.3284115 0.3327925
9         NaN       NaN       NaN
diab
0   0.3287025 0.3420708 0.3292267
1   0.3549009 0.3163546 0.3287445
9       NaN       NaN       NaN
colest
0   0.3499758 0.3174988 0.3325254
1   0.3382244 0.3341382 0.3276374
9       NaN       NaN       NaN
tabaco
1   0.3371538 0.3390640 0.3237822
2   0.3058252 0.3592233 0.3349515
3   0.3297872 0.4007092 0.2695035
4   0.3424759 0.3313566 0.3261675
5   0.3445102 0.3210607 0.3344291
9       NaN       NaN       NaN



        OO         NUTS      LFD
Hypertension
Yes     0.3543614 0.3348910 0.3107477
No      0.3387960 0.3284115 0.3327925
No data           NaN       NaN       NaN
Diabetes
Yes         0.3287025 0.3420708 0.3292267
No      0.3549009 0.3163546 0.3287445
No data      NaN       NaN       NaN
Dislypidaemia
Yes         0.3499758 0.3174988 0.3325254
No      0.3382244 0.3341382 0.3276374
No data       NaN       NaN       NaN
Smoker
Freq        0.3371538 0.3390640 0.3237822
Ex 1year    0.3058252 0.3592233 0.3349515
Ex 2year    0.3297872 0.4007092 0.2695035
Ex 5year    0.3424759 0.3313566 0.3261675
Never   0.3445102 0.3210607 0.3344291
Nodata      NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: You can provide a vector of values in `dnn`.  can you show your expected output

Comment: Updated! I don't use the labels, I am using 0 and 1 provided by as_factor with the haven package

Answer (score 0):

You can use is.nan

```
data <- na.omit(rbind(hta_tb_grupo_p, diab_tb_grupo_p, colest_tb_grupo_p, tabacos_tb_grupo_p))

data[!apply(data, 1, \(x) all(is.nan(x))),]
```

You can use `na.omit(data)` also.